# Ascending sort order Index versus descending sort order index when performing OrderBy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and I am using Sql server 2008 R2 + Entity framework. 
Now on the sql server I have added a unique index on any column that might be ordered by . for example I have created a unique index on the Sql server on the Tag colum and I have defined that the sort order for the index to be Ascending. Now I have some queries inside my application that order the tag ascending while other queries order the Tag descending, as follow:-

```
LatestTechnology = tms.Technologies.Where(a=> !a.IsDeleted && a.IsCompleted).OrderByDescending(a => a.Tag).Take(pagesize).ToList(),;

TechnologyList = tms.Technologies.Where(a=> !a.IsDeleted && a.IsCompleted).OrderBy (a => a.Tag).Take(pagesize).ToList();
```

So my question is whether the two OrderByDescending(a => a.Tag). & OrderBy(a => a.Tag), can benefit from the asending unique index on the sql server on the Tag colum ? or I should define two unique indexes on the sql server one with ascending sort order while the other index with decedning sort order ?
THanks

**EDIT**

the  following query :-

```
LatestTechnology = tms.Technologies.Where(a=> !a.IsDeleted && a.IsCompleted).OrderByDescending(a => a.Tag).Take(pagesize).ToList();
```

will generate the following sql statement as mentioned by the sql server profiler  :-

```
  SELECT TOP (15) 

        [Extent1].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
        [Extent1].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
        [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
        [Extent1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
        [Extent1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
        [Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
        [Extent1].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
        [Extent1].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted]
        FROM [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] <> cast(1 as bit)) AND ([Extent1].[IsCompleted] = 1)
        ORDER BY [Extent1].[Tag] DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> So my question is whether the two OrderByDescending(a => a.Tag). &
>   OrderBy(a => a.Tag), can benefit from the asending unique index on the
>   sql server on the Tag colum ?

Yes, SQL Server can read an index in both directions: as in index definition or in the exact opposite direction.

However, from your intro I suspect that you still have a wrong impression how indexing works for `order by`. If you have both, a `where` clause and an `order by` clause, you must make sure to have a *single* index that covers both clauses! It does not help to have on index for the `where` clause (like on `isDeleted` and `isCompleted` — whatever that is in your example) and another index on `tag`. You need to have a single index that first has the columns of the `where` clause followed by the columns of the `order by` clause (multi-column index).

It can be tricky to make it work correctly, but it's worth the effort especially if your are only fetching the first few rows (like in your example).

If it doesn't work out right away, please have a look at this:

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by

It is generally best to show the actual SQL query—not the .NET source code—when asking for performance advice. Then I could tell you which index to create exactly. At the moment I'm unsure about `isDeleted` and `isCompleted` — are these table columns or expressions that evaluate upon other columns?

**EDIT** (after you added the SQL query)

There are two ways to make your query work as *indexed top-n* query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/260fb/4

The first option is a regular index on the columns from the where clause followed by those from the order by clause. However, as you query uses this filter `IsDeleted <> cast(1 as bit)` it cannot use the index in a order-preserving way. If, however, you re-phrase the query so that it reads like this `IsDeleted = cast(0 as bit)` then it works. Please look at the fiddle, I've prepared everything there. Yes, SQL Server could be smart enough to know that, but it seems like it isn't.

I don't know how to tweak EF to produce the query in the above described way, sorry.

However, there is a second option using a so called filtered index — that is an index that only contains a sub-set of the table rows. It's also in the SQL Fiddle. Here it is important that you add the where clause to the index definition in the very same way as it appears in your query.

In both ways it still works if you change DESC to ASC.

The important part is that the execution plan doesn't show a sort operation. You can also verify this in SQL Fiddle (click on 'View execution plan').

Comment: IsDeleted & isCompleted are two bit columns

Comment: and i have edited my original question with the sql query as indicated by the sql server profiler.

Comment: @johnG Added suggestions above.